# Copy a range and Paste it to a Sheet that is using a Filter

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am attempting to write a script that will copy a range of values from one sheet and paste it on another sheet that is using a filter.

I used the Macro feature but its not working how id like it to after recording the macro

Here is a visual of what im trying to do.

I'd like to copy this range (A3:A30)

[image: img1]

And then paste to another (range is dynamic due to a filter being applied) tab that is using a filter.

[image: img2]

Except what happens is that the macro code will always paste to the hidden rows

````
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A3:A30').activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet6'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A5').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Sheet7!A3:A30').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
};```
````

Comment: Im pretty sure its recognizing the hidden rows instead of pasting to the rows that are not hidden

Comment: Just an advice. Don't use active sheets or cells. You don't need this approach, it makes your code complicated and you run unnecessary lines of code.

Comment: @Marios I was using Tools --> Macros --> Record Macros.  I imagine this isnt the best solution?